# CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator and namespace not found after .net 8 migration

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-migrations

I am upgrading one of our projects from .net6 to .net8 and after updating the Nuget packages CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator cannot be found anymore and the Namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design doesn't seem to be there as well.

.net8 version is 8.0.100 and I have checked that documentation wise nothing actually has changed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.design.csharpmigrationoperationgenerator?view=efcore-8.0

```
namespace My.Object.Db.Data.MigrationContext
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations;

    /// <summary>
    /// MyMigrationOperationGenerator
    /// </summary>
    public class MyMigrationOperationGenerator : CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator
    {
       .... custom code
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 17.8.0 with support for .net8.

[image: Error message in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft this package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is a DevelopmentDependency package so you need to change the package metadata by removing the IncludeAssets attribute from your .csproj file. I found that upgrading to NET 8 added this field back in automatically which caused the breakage.

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <!--<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>-->
  </PackageReference>
```

Comment: thx, already had found that but forgot to answer here. So thank you for answering